# Memory error in GAE python

Tags: google-app-engine

I bulkloaded to the data store 88 entities, each one is composed from
a unicode field (name), and a list field (lst) of 4996 numbers.
The bulk loader section of the list looks like this:

```
property: lst

  external_name: lst

  Type: List
  import_transform: "lambda x:x.split()"
```

After the import I could see in the data store viewer all the entities. 
When I try to run this code:

```
def an(x): 
    return x.name

class Name(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty(unicode)
    lst=db.ListProperty(int)

    class Calc(webapp.RequestHandler):

       def get(self):

           begin=Name.all()

           self.response.out.write('<html><body>')

           self.response.out.write(" ".join(map(an,begin))) 

           self.response.out.write('</body></html>')
```

I got a memory error.
When I erased most of the entities from the data store, and only few left it worked OK.
I added few more and I got memory error again.

Do I have to import csv files with 10 entities each, or can I import any number of entities in the file?
what did I do wrong anyway?

I'm a newbie in GAE, so please be patient.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please [don't sign your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures), and please [do read the formatting tips](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: "A memory error"? Exactly what exception do you get, and where? On the client or the server?

Comment: I don't know if it is the server or the client, it doesn't like this line of code: self.response.out.write(" ".join(map(an,begin)))
and it says at the end of list MemoryError

Comment: It is the server, and in the end of a long error list written MemoryError.